# Volume of the solid that lies under $x+y+z=10$ and above the triangular region $R$ that is bounded by the y-axis and the lines $y=5$, $y=x$.

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

Volume of the solid that lies under $x+y+z=10$ and above the triangular region $R$ that is bounded by the y-axis and the lines $y=5$, $y=x$.

I've been stuck on this question for a while, I know its gonna be a double integral I just can't get the boundaries.

Comment: Please indicate what you have tried so far? This will help people see where you are stuck and better tailor their answer to help you.

Comment: since i wont use the z in the double integral i ended up with this z=10-x-y (not really sure about that part). That's all I have till now

Answer (score 0):

Firstly draw out $R$.

[image]

This will help you think about the bounds of your integral. This will also help you decide if it is better to integrate over $x$ first or $y$.

There are two ways to write the integral (based on which variable is integrated first):

$$\int_0^5\int_x^5 10-x-y dydx$$

OR

$$\int_0^5\int_0^y 10-x-y dxdy$$

Comment: I found out that the boundaries should be from some number to 5, but how did you know them? As in x to 5 and 0 to y(the first integrals of each equation).Also why does the outer integral in the second equation starts from 1?. Why are't the integral's go from 0 to 5? I see that the triangle goes from 0 to 5 on y axis and the same on the x axis.

Comment: Oops the 1 was a typo. Sorry.

Comment: Yeah I was kinda worried because I tried both of them out and I got different results, but no worries. Thank you